# Encode base64 custom field link wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, base64, encode, advanced-custom-fields

I want to encode my custom field links in Wordpress. I use a plugin to generate my custom field : Advanced Custom Fields.

I found a code with Php and JS

In single.php

```
function cl($url) {
    $taille = strlen($url);
    $urlcode = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $taille; $i++) {
        if ($i % 2) {
            $urlcode.= "ajoutdunechainedecaractere" . $url{$i};
        }
        else {
            $urlcode.= $url{$i};
        }
    }
    return base64_encode($urlcode);
}
```

I have a JS file

```
 function btob(text) {
   text = text.replace(/\s/g,""); if (!(/^[a-z0-9\+\/\s]+\={0,2}$/i.test(text)) || text.length % 4 > 0) { return text; }
   var digits = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/', cur, prev, digitNum, i=0, result = [], text = text.replace(/=/g, "");
   while (i < text.length){
       cur = digits.indexOf(text.charAt(i)); digitNum = i++ % 4;
       switch (digitNum) {
           case 1: result.push(String.fromCharCode(prev << 2 | cur >> 4)); break;
           case 2: result.push(String.fromCharCode((prev & 0x0f) << 4 | cur >> 2)); break;
           case 3: result.push(String.fromCharCode((prev & 3) << 6 | cur)); break;
       }
       prev = cur;
   }
   return result.join('');
}

function transformText() {
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
       for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
               if ((s[i].className.indexOf('lc') != -1)){

                       var lien = btob(s[i].getAttribute('data')).replace(/ajoutdunechainedecaractere/g,"");

           var lnk = document.createElement('a'); 
           lnk.href = lien; 
           lnk.innerHTML = s[i].innerHTML; 
           s[i].innerHTML = ''; 
           s[i].appendChild(lnk);

           if( s[i].hasAttribute("onclick") )
           //on récupère l'attribut onclick pour l'ajouter dans le lien
           {
               lnk.setAttribute('onclick', s[i].getAttribute('onclick'));
           }
        }
}
window.onload=transformText;
```

To display my link without encoding it I need to put that in my single.php

```
<?php the_field(lien); ?>
```

For encoding link I need replace this by that code, encoded is OK:

```
<span class="lc" data="<?php echo cl("http://www.exemple.com"); ?>" onclick="test()"> MY ANCHOR </span>
```

But if I replace "http://www.exemple.com" with my customfield

```
 <span class="lc" data="<?php echo cl(the_field(lien)); ?>" onclick="test()"> MY ANCHOR </span>
```

I don't have an encoded url, only a normal url.

**So please what am I doing wrong ?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why did you chose to do base64 encoding?

Answer (score 1):

You need `get_field`: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/

```
<span class="lc" data="<?php echo cl(get_field(lien)); ?>" onclick="test()"> MY ANCHOR </span>
```

`the_field` actually echos the value, `get_field` returns it.